# Efficient way to read from a wordlist and hash?

Tags: arrays, c, string, hash, md5

I have two functions, how can I optimize this code? In wordlist function I read from a file with fscanf, i use a temporary array to do the hash, so I can keep the read line when I have to print it, then I compare the passed digest with the computed digest (to crack it). In the md5 function I have "result" array with MD5 function return value, and then I copy the array in a string because I have to cast from char array to hex string. Is there something wrong? The functions work, but can I fix something to do it faster or more correct?

```
void wordlistMD5(char digest[], char hashtype[], FILE *wordlist) {
    char line [512];
    while (fscanf(wordlist,"%s\n",line) != -1) {
        char hash[512] = {0};
        strncpy(hash,line,strlen(line));
        if (strcmp(md5(hash), digest) == 0) {
            printf("Found!\nhash %s %s -> %s\n", hashtype, digest, line);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Found nothing.\n");
    fclose(wordlist);
}

char *md5(char *string){
    unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    int i;
    MD5((const unsigned char *)string, strlen(string), result);
    for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        sprintf(string + 2*i,"%02x",result[i]);
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Just trying to understand the intent of the code here. Do you have a specific problem other than "make faster"? If you stored the hashes as binary values you could do direct comparisons a lot more quickly than leaning on the slow `strcmp`. Alternatively, instead of a linear scan, sort the hashes by value and use a binary search.

Comment: @tadman I wrote the intent of the code right up here, I rewrite it for clarity. I want to understand if this code has something wrong  and then if I can do better (example, if doing the sprinf is slow, or if there is a way to use one array instead of two with the strncpy and something like this). The hashes are stored in txt, not in binary, so thanks anyway

Comment: You can always convert them to binary. It'll make your matching vastly faster since you can treat an MD5 hash as two `uint64_t` values, as in `struct md5hash { uint64_t a,b; }` so `if (hash1.a==hash2.a && hash1.b == hash2.b)` and you're done, two comparisons max, plus will make the file you have to read 50% smaller.

Comment: Also since hashes are always going to be the same length, skip the `fscanf` at least and just read in chunks of the correct length.